# Error installing docker on Windows 7

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm new to docker. I just downloaded the docker toolbox for windows 7 but it isn't working.

When starting Docker Quick start Terminal : [looks like something went wrong on step checking status on default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9hs5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a docker issue, this is an issue with virtualbox as the error states.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to VirtualBox and its "Host-Only Ethernet Adapter", on which docker depends on.

This is the error-text, which is visible in the console of Virtual Box:

```
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: E_FAIL
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
```

[Full Console Output](https://pastebin.com/dHCc6V6L)

Steps to see same issue in **VirtualBox Manager** :

- Start **Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager**
- Click on network and settings --> dialog opens.
- Choose "Host-only Adapter" and for name "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"

more about **Host-Only Ethernet Adapter**
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly